# Laravel backpack javascript. Crud is not defined

Tags: javascript, laravel-backpack

I want to implement an example from the Javascript documentation of the Laravel backpack.
Created a crud file. I placed the js file connection in the setupCreateOperation method.

```
protected function setupCreateOperation()
{
   $this->crud->setValidation(ProductRequest::class);
   $this->crud->addFields([]);
   Widget::add()->type('script')->content('assets/js/admin/forms/product.js');
}
```

Inside this JS file I placed the code

```
crud.field('parent').onChange(function(field) {
    console.log(field.value);
}).change();
```

Developer console displays error on first row

```
crud is not defined
```

Comment: Perhaps you have an old version of Backpack, which does not support it yet? What does “php artisan backpack:version” output? Make sure you’re using the latest Backpack/CRUD v5 release.

Comment: I checked the version first - 5.0.9

Comment: Ah, there you go. A “composer update backpack/crud” should fix it for you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the problem here may be an overwrite in `form_content.blade.php`.
If you have this file overridden in your `resources/` folder you should check the source file and do the necessary changes https://github.com/Laravel-Backpack/CRUD/blob/main/src/resources/views/crud/form_content.blade.php

Specifically `@include('crud::inc.form_fields_script')`.

Let me know if that wasn't the issue.

Cheers

Comment: Thank you. There was indeed a mistake. Composer update did not help, strange. The problem disappeared when I created the file.